# jQuery if width is less than 767 the previous code should not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Problem: I want that the code in the if statement would work only if the screen width is greater than 767px, and if it is less than 767px the previous code shouldn't work, how to do it?

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(document).width() > 767) {
    $('.navigation-hide').hide();

   $("nav").mouseenter(function() {    
       $('.navigation-hide').stop().fadeIn(500);       
   });

   $('nav').mouseleave(function() {    
        $('.navigation-hide').stop().fadeOut(500);         
   });
}
        else {
            break;
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to use JS in this way.

You can use CSS to show/hide elements depending on screen size [using media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navigation-hide {
      display: none;
  }
  nav:hover .navigation-hide {
      display: block;
  }
}
```

You can use CSS transitions to achieve the fade effect.

Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v34xkf5L/)

```
.navigation-hide {
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s, left 0.5s 0.5s;
}

nav:hover .navigation-hide {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: I can't use media rules for this, because i need with JS to fade in or fade out an element smooth when it is hovered.

Answer (score 1):

It should be achieved using CSS's media queries and effects, see this https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12782/

however if you insist using jQuery, then check this out

```
$(document).ready(callbackReady);
$(window).resize(callbackResize);

var isWidthReady = false;
var callbackReady = function() {
    $("nav").mouseenter(function() {
        if(isWidthReady) {
            $('.navigation-hide').stop().fadeIn(500);     
        }           
    });
    $('nav').mouseleave(function() {
        if(isWidthReady) {
            $('.navigation-hide').stop().fadeOut(500);  
        }
    });
}
var callbackResize = function() {
    if ($(document).width() > 767) {
        $('.navigation-hide').hide();
        isWidthReady = true;
    }
    else {
        isWidthReady = false;
    }
};
```

> Note: do not implement any event handler inside another recurring event (resize() in your case) unless
>   you are creating a new element dynamically or removing and reattaching an event.

Comment: Could you show me your html as well so that I could improve the answer? and what is your `".navigation-hide"` supposed to do?

Comment: Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12779/
the jQuery code should only work if the screen width is greater than 767px, the error: if the screen has the mobile version navbar then try to open it and move the mouse cursor to the opened area and move then the cursor out of the area, then you will see the error what i am trying to do.

Comment: I'm afraid you are doing it wrong, you should only use CSS's media queries instead of window.resize in your case. Here's a https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12782/ hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Use an if statement with 
window.innerWidth!

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
if(window.innerWidth >= 767){
 $(window).resize(function() { if ($(document).width() > 767) { $('.navigation-hide').hide(); $("nav").mouseenter(function() { $('.navigation-hide').stop().fadeIn(500); }); $('nav').mouseleave(function() { $('.navigation-hide').stop().fadeOut(500); }); } else { break; } }); }});
```

Comment: This code isn't working for me but i don't know why, could it be that i can't use a break statement here?

Comment: It wasn't an error, the code just wasn't working and i think that the break statement shouldn't be in use here, but i dont know exactly why..